# LINQ query on datatable, join multiple selects

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have below linq query on a datatable:

```
string[] sourceNames = this.dt
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("Name"))
                    .ToArray();

string[] sourceSurnames = this.dt
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("Surname"))
        .ToArray();

string[] sourceSecondSurnames = this.dt
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("Second Surname"))
        .ToArray();

string[] src = sourceNames.Union(sourceSurnames).Union(sourceSecondSurnames).ToArray();
```

Datatable has some fields, some of them are above: Names, Surname, Second Surname... among others.

What I am trying to do here is join all the three linq queries in only one. The final goal is to get an array of strings, that is, src.

How can I do this?

Comment: So what isn't working with the code above?

Comment: What does your current code do? How does that differ from what you **want** it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it in a single query easily with `SelectMany`:

```
string[] src = dt.AsEnumerable()
   .SelectMany(row => new[]{ row.Field<String>("Name"),row.Field<String>("Surname"),row.Field<String>("Second Surname")} )
   .Distinct()
   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            var everything = dt
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => x.Field<string>("Name"))
            .ToArray().Concat(dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => x.Field<string>("Surname"))
            .ToArray()).Concat(dt
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => x.Field<string>("Second Surname"))
                .ToArray());
```

Using Concat could be solving this.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: It is an answer and a question towards to user that asked a question in order to check if it solved the problem for him.

Comment: Answers shouldn't contain questions though, that's what comments are for.

Answer (score 1):

in query syntax it would be

```
var src = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()              
           from n in new[]{ row.Field<String>("Name"),row.Field<String>("Surname"),row.Field<String>("SecondSurname")} 
           select  n).Distinct().ToArray();
```